# Switch over between Tabs in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a tab host contain four tabs,in my first tab i have two button , when i click first button i need to go to the second tab in tab host, similarly when i click the third button i need to go to third tab .

If anyone know the solution please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The TabHost has a method called 'setCurrentTab(int index)' which you can call inside your button's onclick handler. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab(int)

Comment: from an activity how can i access the tabHost;

Comment: You can try '(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.the_tab_host_id_that_you_have)' which will find the TabHost in your activity's layout.

Answer (score 0):

Karthi,

This can be done with the [`setCurrentTab()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29) method from `TabHost`.  You may want to follow this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html